# How Can I Populate JSF selectonemenu From Loop or Array

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I am VERY new to JSF, and I need some help doing, what I thought would be, a very simple task. I would like to populate a selectonemenu from an array or loop or something. I have a form where I want the user to enter their DOB. All I want is a simple list where they can select from 1..31 for the day of month. I don't want to have 31

```
<f:selectItem value="n" />
```

tags. I attempted to put a "getDates" method in my backing bean, but that didn't work well. Any advice on how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Psssh.. Put your mouse above the `[selectonemenu]` tag which you've placed on the question yourself until a black info box pops up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`<f:selectItems>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) instead of [`<f:selectItem>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItem.html). The `<f:selectItems>` can take a `List<T>` or `T[]` or even a `Map<K,V>`.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
private String selectedItem;
private List<String> availableItems;
```

#### See also:

- [Our `h:selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) - contains lot of concrete examples